# Add surface area from one Circle to another Circle

Tags: java, graphics, 2d

So I'm working on a small game where there are a bunch of random Circles moving around and you control one Circle yourself. If a circle intersects another circle, the bigger one should absorb the smaller one.

So far my method is pretty shitty since it only grows the bigger circle while they are intersecting. Which leads to unrealistic size changes depending on how long they are intersecting.
*player* and *enemy* are rectangles.

```
if(intersecting(player, enemy)){
        if(player.width > enemy.width) {
            player.width += 1; //increase size
            player.height += 1;
            player_posx -= 0.5; // compensate that circle increases to bottom right
            player_posy -= 0.5;
        } else if (player.width < enemy.width) {
            player.width -= 1; //decrease size
            player.height -= 1;
            player += 0.5;
            player += 0.5;
        }
    }
```

Instead I want to accurately add the area of one circle to the other. My problem is that the player and enemy class updates constantly and I can't calculate the area difference between two intersecting circles because they constanly change their size when intersecting.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve.  If it's simply to create one circle whose area is equal to the sum of the areas of the two original circles, that's easy to calculate (using A = pi * r^2).  If it's something else, you may need to draw a diagram to help illustrate.

Comment: Yes I know how to calculate the area, The problem is that it shouldn't add one area to the other instantly but add so much of one area to another (and substract this part of the smaller area) until they don't intersect anymore.

[GIF showing](http://gfycat.com/ScalyPointedIberiannase)

Green circle is the moveable player. Red indicates bigger circle, blue indicates smaller circle. If the player moves next to a red circle but only slightly touches it. It should decrease the players size.

Comment: The problem is that for example the player is moving really fast and is passing trough a big red circle within 5 frames of the game, the player will only loose 5 pixels in size. The other way round if the palyer is moving really slow and absorbs smaller circle, the player increases by the number of frames while intersecting.